How to force the model to use different greeting in emails
I'm using llama2 model and I'm asking it to generate emails.
it usually start the email with 'hi' or 'hey'.
I would like it to be more creative and randomize the greeting.
changing parameters like temperature/top_k/.. didn't really helped.
Thank you.

If changing parameters like temperature/top_k/... didn't help, another option is listing greeting alternatives in the prompt.

There are 3 things that can be done to change the behavior of an LLM.

Parameter tuning: Changing parameters like temperature, top-k etc. But these are nothing but some tempering/shortlisting on the probability distribution over all possible tokens from where the next token will be selected. Changing them will indeed create variations in the final outcome, either by making the completion behavior more predictable or less predictable. But this doesn't guarantee that they will end up becoming the exact format you want.

Prompt Engineering: LLMs are super sensitive to the prompt. But unfortunately, there no absolute perfect prompt, although there are some best practices which generally works. But in summary, the prompt should be clear, unambiguous and should contain example. Here is a guideline you can follow.

Fine Tuning: If you want to stick to a particular LLM and the first two options fail, then consider fine tuning the model. This will help your model to be more aligned with your need.


There is another option I didn't mention here, which is switching to a different model which works better. As you have referred LLAMA2, I am assuming you want to use open-source models. Personally, I have found LLMA2 is quite stubborn and often ignores the prompt. Other alternatives like Mistral seems to be better aligned in terms of following instructions and the statistics also says the same. There are also other newer open-source models have come out including LLAMA3 which are better. Although, I didn't try them all. But the final suggestion is, don't fix yourself to a single model if you find it hard to tune.
